# What is difference between a Screen and View in COCOMO-II model?

Tags: design, estimation

My question is related to software cost estimation. In Software Engineering, COCOMO I or II, are for investigating cost, effort, deployment of staff and ascertaining an accurate road map of precise time lines of the entire project. COCOMO-II comprises of four sub-models individually addressing the Application Composition (gathers application perspective consisting of a number of screens, reports and 3GL components), Early Design, Reuse and Post-Architecture.

In the Application Composition sub-model of COCOMO-II, Screen and Report are Classified based on number of source data tables and number of views Screen/Report will need. see https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://www.sel.unsl.edu.ar/pro/proyec/paginas1/tutorials/Lect03-COCOMOII.doc

My question is what is relation between a Screen and View? What is meant by Screen is simple because it has <3 views.

My understanding is that screen is a like a window as we see in Microsoft windows and 2 views of a screen means it will be displayed on two monitors. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that screen is a like a window as we see in Microsoft windows and 2 views of a screen means it will be displayed on two monitors. Am I right?

No, as I understand it a screen in this context **is** a window.  A "view" is effectively a different usage "Mode" of the same window.  Think of a security based example: a normal salesperson and a manager could use the same form but with very different options available.  You wouldn't create two nearly identical forms, you'd create one with a bunch of conditional setup based on the role of the logged in user.